# Django pass variables from views to Ajax

Tags: javascript, python-3.x, django, ajax

In my django project i have a method in a view where execute some calculation e define a variable for message and pass to my Ajax method.
I do:

views.py

```
...
try:
    msg="Prodotto inserito nel carrello"
    if request.POST['pgift'] == "true":
        <do some calculations>
    else:
        msg = "Non hai abbastanza punti per acquistare utilizzando il gift"
except Exception as e:
        msg = "Errore imprevisto. Riprova ad inserire il prodotto o contattaci per maggiori informazioni"

response = []
valrst = {'r_msg': msg}
response.append(valrst)
json = simplejson.dumps(response)

return HttpResponse(
    json, content_type='application/json'
)
```

then in my js code:

test.js

```
function update_item(upd_id, qta_val) {
//oCtemplates = document.getElementById("t_select");

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/update_cart/",
    data: { "updid": upd_id, "nqta": qta_val },
    success: function (data) {

        $.each(data, function (index) {

        });

    }
});
```

How can i pass my django msg variable into my js for ceate an alert with this data?

So many thanks in advance
Manuel

Comment: what does `data` has ? Do `console.log(data)` you will see result inside browser console.

Answer (score 0):

if update-cart is the view you are hitting in your ajax request:

```
      $.ajax({
         type: "POST",
         url: "/update_cart/",
         data: { "updid": upd_id, "nqta": qta_val },
         success: function (data) {
          alert(data);
                  }
            });
```

On your view try changing the response method:

```
   from django.http import JsonResponse
   response = dict()
   response.update({'r_msg': msg})
   return JsonResponse(response)
```

Comment: Thanks, i try but i get a blank Array ([])

Comment: I updated my answer to support a different built in response method.

Comment: I get Array(0) again

Comment: I need to see more code to help. I would put a default string in the msg variable and bypass your if and try, just to sanity check and make sure there is actually data being passed and your variables are not empty.